# Is there any difference if I pass a user credentials as a payload, in the header, a parameter, or a query?

Tags: security, authentication, credentials

I am making an API for my app and I want to know if there is any difference security wise whether I pass a user's credentials as a payload, in the header, as a parameter, or as a query? Besides security, are there any differences at all such as performance, is one faster that the other?

This is for authenticating a user via username and password, from the client to the server in a GET request.

Answer (score 2):

There is lot of difference when you send the credentials as payload or header or param or query. But it depends if you are using **http or https**. If its **http** then it is not at all recommended that you send the credentials at any cost over these mediums, as the request and the data can easily be traced. In case of https, you can do it but the most respected way of doing it would be to use Basic Authentication mechanism thats why its build or use OAUTH.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that even with https passing credentials in the url will result in plain text credentials being stored in the client device and server logs.

Comment: Well, I am using https and the `hapi-auth-jwt2` plugin. I am thinking about going with payload or header...

Answer (score 0):

GET method is intended to be used to get some information from server, POST - to send data or request an action, so GET shouldn't be used for that.

You shouldn't pass authentication credentials as request parameters since they may easily leak at proxy servers, interim routers or insecure networks.

Passing them in a POST payload or request headers would minimize the probability of leaks, but anyway secure browser-to-server channel (https) must be used anyway.

While handling the authentication request on server make sure it has come from your own and not some other server. That can be implemented by using some server-generated key/token with limited lifetime and checking that token for validity when handling the POST request with credentials sent from browser.

If you issue some kind of authentication token or session id from server and keep it in a cookie, you should set [HttpOnly flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) to prevent access to them from JavaScript.

If you develop stateless single-page application, consider using [JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://jwt.io/) to handle authentication/authorization claims, that would minimize the need to request permanent storage (database) on a backend and help with authentication procedures for multiple distributed resources.